# Custom Angular Tree using ngTemplateOutlet and ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create a custom N level tree component but **I have problem rendering the tree leaves (nodes without any children) using ng-template**. The nodes with children renders correctly but the last nodes won't render anything.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
export class Node
{
    Name: string;
    IsExpanded = false;
    IsExpandable = true;
    Children = new Array<any>();
}
```

**TreeNodeComponent**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input, ContentChild, TemplateRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
// tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
selector: 'tree-node',
styleUrls: ['tree-node.component.scss'],
templateUrl: 'tree-node.component.html'
})
export class TreeNodeComponent
{

@Input() Children: Array<any>;

@Input() Key: string;

@ContentChild('LeafTemplate') LeafTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;

}
```

**tree-node.component.html**

```
<div class="tree-node"
 *ngFor="let child of Children">
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="child.IsExpandable"
                   hideToggle="true"
                   (opened)="child.IsExpanded=true"
                   (closed)="child.IsExpanded=false"
                   [(expanded)]="child.IsExpanded">
<mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="'48px'"
                            [expandedHeight]="'54px'">
  <mat-panel-title>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!child.IsExpanded">chevron_right</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="child.IsExpanded">expand_more</mat-icon>
    {{child.Name}}
  </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>

<ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
  <tree-node [Children]="child.Children"
             Key="Children">
  </tree-node>
</ng-template>

</mat-expansion-panel>

<ng-template *ngIf="!child.IsExpandable"
           [ngTemplateOutlet]="LeafTemplate"
           [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item:child}"></ng-template>

</div>
```

And using it as:

```
<tree-node [Children]="Nodes" Key="Children">
    <ng-template #LeafTemplate
                 let-item="item">
        <h4> {{item.Name}}</h4>
    </ng-template>
</tree-node>
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Here is its [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybqdqb)

Comment: cab you create stackblitz?